# Redirect the "puts" command output to a log file

Tags: ruby, daemon

I am working on creating a daemon in Ruby using the daemons gem. I want to add output from the daemon into a log file. I am wondering what is the easiest way to redirect `puts` from the console to a log file.

Comment: Use this `LOGGER ||= Logger.new("| tee #{settings.root}/log/migration_script_logger.log", "monthly")` , this will do both

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I should recommend to use ruby logger, it is better than puts, you can have multiple log levels that you can turn on/off: debug, warn, info,error, etc.

```
 logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
 logger = Logger.new("/var/log/my-daemon.log")
```

I use runit package to manage ruby services, it has svlogd than will redirect daemon output to log file, here is run script for logger process:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

LOG=/var/log/my-daemon

test -d "$LOG" || mkdir -p -m2750 "$LOG" && chown nobody:adm "$LOG"
exec chpst -unobody svlogd -tt "$LOG"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  What if you can't control who is doing the _puts_ and you want to to capture things that would normally write to STDOUT and instead write them to a file?

Answer (score 39):

If you need to capture both STDERR and STDOUT and don't want to resort to logging:

```
$stdout.reopen("my.log", "w")
$stdout.sync = true
$stderr.reopen($stdout)
```

To restore:

```
$stdout = STDOUT
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked mighty fine in conjunction with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993071/how-to-controller-start-kill-a-background-process-server-app-in-ruby)!

Comment: what if you want puts to still go to terminal, as well as to log file?  e.g. behaviour like `ruby myscript.rb | tee my.log`

Comment: @wim I know this comment is a bit old, but there are some solutions listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407141/how-can-i-have-ruby-logger-log-output-to-stdout-as-well-as-file/

Comment: The command `$stdout.reopen("my.log", "w")` breaks my rails console (I have to kill the process). Looking into other solutions.

Comment: @AlexC, in Rails there's the Rails logger: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
$stdout = File.new( '/tmp/output', 'w' )
```

To restore:

```
$stdout = STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can redefine the `puts` command? Works probably only in a single file/class

```
def puts(message)
   #write message to file
end
```