# How can I capture Rake output when invoked from with a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, stdout

I am writing a web-based dev-console for Rails development. In one of my controller actions, I am calling Rake, but I am unable to capture any of the output that Rake generates. For example, here is some sample code, from the controller:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'tasks/rails'
require 'stringio'

...

def show_routes

  @results = capture_stdout { Rake.tasks['routes'].invoke }

  # @results is nil -- the capture_stdout doesn't catpure anything that Rake generates

end

def capture_stdout
  s = StringIO.new
  $stdout = s
  yield
  s.string
ensure
  $stdout = STDOUT
end
```

Does anybody know why I can't capture the Rake output? I've tried going through the Rake source, and I can't see where it fires a new process or anything, so I think I ought to be able to do this.

Many thanks!
Adrian

---

I have since discovered the correct way to call Rake from inside Ruby that works much better:

```
Rake.application['db:migrate:redo'].reenable
Rake.application['db:migrate:redo'].invoke
```

Strangely, some rake tasks work perfectly now (routes), some capture the output the first time the run and after that are always blank (db:migrate:redo) and some don't seem to ever capture output (test). Odd.

Answer (score 4):

While this is some kind of a hack (since Rack is written in ruby), you could use open3's [popen3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) method and invoke the rake task like you would from the commandline.

In your case you would use it like that

```
require 'open3'

buffer = []
Open3::popen3("rake db:migrate:redo") do |stdin,stdout,stderr|
  begin
    while line = stdout.readline
      buffer << line
    end
  rescue
  end
end
```

So you would end up with all lines that rake returned to stdout in `buffer`. Maybe this works more reliable, though I would recommend investigating the source of the odd behaviour 
 you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know ZenTest is able to capture "puts"-statements through "until_capture" and I even found someone who wrote about a custom implementation by extending the Kernel module and redirecting $stdout to an instance of StringIO.

Hope that helps:
http://thinkingdigitally.com/archive/capturing-output-from-puts-in-ruby/

You may also want to check out OutputCatcher by Matthias Hennemeyer:
http://github.com/mhennemeyer/output_catcher

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, capturing stdio in the kernel module seems to give exactly the same results as I've been getting with my local capture_output method.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1174 of gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:

```
  # Send the message to the default rake output (which is $stderr).
  def rake_output_message(message)
    $stderr.puts(message)
  end
  private :rake_output_message
```

Perhaps try capturing STDERR as well as STDOUT?

I'm not saying that all output is done through `$stderr`, but rake itself seems to have set up that convention, perhaps somewhere along the line someone made certain rake tasks overwrite puts to direct to `$stderr`.

I haven't tested the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick for me:

```
$stdout.reopen("my.log", "w")
$stdout.sync = true

# do your thing

$stdout = STDOUT
```

Seen at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480439/21217