# rails - Redirecting console output to a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, console

On a bash console, if I do this:

```
cd mydir
ls -l > mydir.txt
```

The > operator captures the standard input and redirects it to a file; so I get the listing of files in `mydir.txt` instead of in the standard output.

Is there any way to do something similar on the rails console?

I've got a ruby statement that generates lots of prints (~8k lines) and I'd like to be able to see it completely, but the console only "remembers" the last 1024 lines or so. So I thought about redirecting to a file - If anyone knows a better option, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use override `$stdout` to redirect the console output:

```
$stdout = File.new('console.out', 'w')
```

You may also need to call this once:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

To restore:

```
$stdout = STDOUT
```

Comment: It didn't work for me until I added `$stdout.sync=true`.  Edited.

Comment: `$stdout.reopen("my.log", "w")` seems to be a more elegant solution, seen at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2480439/21217

Comment: `$stdout = File.new('console.out', 'w')` taking really long time. I am using windows. Not sure if that is the reason!

Comment: You may need to close the file to capture all the data. I use `std=$stdout ; f=File.new("/tmp/console.out", 'w')` followed by `$stdout=f ; pp Foo.where(id: [100..1234]); f.close; $stdout=std`. Otherwise final pieces of data do not appear.

Answer (score 162):

A quick one-off solution:

```
irb:001> f = File.new('statements.xml', 'w')
irb:002> f << Account.find(1).statements.to_xml
irb:003> f.close
```

Create a JSON fixture:

```
irb:004> f = File.new(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/qbo/amy_cust.json', 'w')
irb:005> f << JSON.pretty_generate((q.get :customer, 1).as_json)
irb:006> f.close
```

Comment: It gave me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'statements' for #<Blog:0x007fdaadbe4530>` or `undefined method 'statements' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fdaaaf4f880>` :(

Comment: Where is the file `statements.xml` get saved in the system. I cannot find the file.

Comment: This is the better answer to show how to save specific record dump rather than telling someone to add yet another gem or plugin (SO tired of software recommendations when not needed) OR dumping everything in console to file. Voted up.

Comment: @SujitS - The file gets saved into the directory from which you executed `rails console` (most likely your app's root directory). (At least this was the case for me.)

Comment: Variation on the solution is: `f = File.new('/tmp/statements.xml', 'w')` then `f.puts Account.find(1)`  (or whatever is the query). Finally, closing the file: `f.close`.
This worked properly when doing a query in gitlab-rails console.

Answer (score 20):

Apart from Veger's answer, there is one of more way to do it which also provides many other additional options.

Just open your rails project directory and enter the command:

```
rails c | tee output.txt
```

tee command also has many other options which you can check out by:

```
man tee
```

Comment: this didn't work for me.. 
I tried running `rails server | tee file.txt` and there's no output to STDOUT or the file. I just think the server fails to start in this case.

Comment: server prints to stderr I think, there should be options in the tee command to redirect that as well.

Comment: Yes, do something like `rails console 2>&1 | tee file.txt`. Not an option in tee, just simple redirection of stderr to stdout so both end up in your file.txt.

Comment: The file ended up full of console colour codes.
Use `pp` to get output without colour codes.

Answer (score 4):

If you write the following code in your environment file, it should work.

```
if "irb" == $0
  config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('path_to_log_file.txt'))
end
```

You can also rotate the log file using

```
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('path_to_log_file.txt'), number_of_files, file_roation_size_threshold)
```

For logging only active record related operations, you can do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('path_to_log_file.txt'))
```

This also lets you have different logger config/file for different environments.

Comment: This is helpful, but the other answer does what I wanted in a simpler way. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Using Hirb, you can choose to log only the Hirb output to a text file.
That makes you able to still see the commands you type in into the console window, and just the model output will go to the file.

From the [Hirb readme](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb):

Although views by default are printed to STDOUT, they can be easily modified to write anywhere:

```
# Setup views to write to file 'console.log'.
>> Hirb::View.render_method = lambda {|output| File.open("console.log", 'w') {|f| f.write(output) } }

# Doesn't write to file because Symbol doesn't have a view and thus defaults to irb's echo mode.
>> :blah
=> :blah

# Go back to printing Hirb views to STDOUT.
>> Hirb::View.reset_render_method
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `script` utility if you are on Unix-based OS.

`script -c "rails runner -e development lib/scripts/my_script.rb" report.txt`

That helped me capture a Rails runner script's very-very long output easily to a file.

I tried using redirecting to a file but it got written only at the end of script (as in when the script execution ended). That didn't helped me because I had few interactive commands in my script.

Then I used just `script` and then ran the `rails runner` in script session but it didn't wrote everything. Then I found this `script -c "runner command here" output_file` and it saved all the output as was desired. This was on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

References:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/290322/how-to-get-and-copy-a-too-long-output-completely-in-terminal#comment1668695_715798

[Writing Ruby Console Output to Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720150/writing-ruby-console-output-to-text-file#comment86906526_8720196)

Answer (score 2):

Use [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb). It automatically pages any output in irb that is longer than a screenful. Put this in a console session to see this work:

```
>> require 'rubygems'
>> require 'hirb'
>> Hirb.enable
```

For more on how this works, [read this post](http://tagaholic.me/2009/06/19/page-irb-output-and-improve-ri-with-hirb.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I wasn't looking for pagination; I wanted to see everything on a single page.