# Writing Ruby Console Output to Text File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rubygems

I'm trying to run a Ruby application, which outputs information to the console. I'd like to make this output get saved to a text/log file.
Is this even possible? There must be a flag for ruby to do this right?

Comment: Do you want to do this within the Ruby application, or within the terminal that runs the Ruby application?

Answer (score 6):

Use [shell redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

```
ruby script.rb > out.txt
rails server > out.txt
```

On another note, you may also redirect $stdout, $stderr:

```
$stdout = File.new('/path/to/out.txt', 'w')
```

http://eddymulyono.livejournal.com/65791.html

Comment: this does work, but only after the script has been excecuted. I would like to see the output as it occurs (as this txt file is being loaded into a web page to view the console)

Comment: i'm a noob at ruby, the script outputs it's data using puts. How will changing stdout change where puts goes? Sorry for this.

Comment: Just looked at your link, but it doesn't seem to be making these files that a specify.

Comment: @nickw444 Because puts writes to stdout.

Comment: `script -c "rails runner -e development lib/scripts/my_script.rb" report.txt` helped me to capture a Rails runner script's very-very long output easily to a file. I tried using redirecting to a file but it got written only at the end of script. That didn't helped me because I had few interactive commands in my script. Then I used just `script` on my and then ran the `rails runner` in script session but it didn't wrote everything. Then I found this `script -c "runner command here" output_file` and it saved all the output as was desired. This was on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I found reference to my posted solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/290322/how-to-get-and-copy-a-too-long-output-completely-in-terminal#comment1668695_715798