# Ruby on Rails console export table to excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, export-to-excel, rails-console

Ruby on Rails 3

I have a table that is not shown on my application. I want to export the table to excel from the console.

Is there way to export a database table to an excel file from the console?

Thank you

Here is what I have so far:

```
require 'csv'

file = "#{Rails.root}/public/survey.csv"

userrefs = Survey.all

CSV.open( file, 'w' ) do |writer|
 userrefs.each do |ur|
   writer << ur.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
 end
end
```

When I enter require 'csv' it returns false. How do you make it true?
Also, the *column_names is undefined.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461503/rails-redirecting-console-output-to-a-file

Comment: @SamD that question does not help with the file format. I can easily get the table in a txt format. I would just copy and paste it if anything.

Comment: instead of txt you can run format.xls on a partial with the table only. like here http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: This is in the application though. My table is not viewed anywhere in my application. I need to do it from console

Comment: you can still run format.xls in console after instantiating the object that you want to export to excel

Comment: @Sam D Your way of running format.xls in console seems to be the most user friendly and long time solution. Please post as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments an easy approach is using format.xls function to render an excel file from the console. Ryan Bates [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) covers Excel outputs extensively.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the database table using the existing driver or, if you prefer a more high-level API, you can create an ActiveRecord model or use the Sequel gem.

Once connected, simply use the [Ruby CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) (it's in the standard library, so no additional library is required) to dump the content into a CSV file.

CSV files can be easily read from Excel.

PS. Just to use the appropriate words, that is not a Rails table. It's a database table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by connect to the database. Also, how do you use the library to dump the file? I see in the link it has a do loop. Is that run at the console?

Comment: Yes, you can perform everything from a console.

Comment: The site uses all those titles that is very confusing. Which is all at once? Also, where in the cmd is the table specified? Could you place an example?

Comment: Instead of having me writing the code for you, according to the spirit of StackOverflow, try to study and write a solution. Then come back and post what you did so that we can comment it and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting approach could be using the activeadmin gem, it's easy to install and allow you to export your tables to csv.

http://www.activeadmin.info/