# Is there a grep-like function in pry console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I want to use a grep-like function in pry console in rails. For example, when I have a model like this:

```
pry(main)> show-model Post
Company
  id: integer
  title: string
  author: string
  content: text
  created_at: datetime
  updated_at: datetime
```

I want to filter the output like:

```
pry(main)> show-model Post --grep "string"
  title: string
  author: string
```

or

```
pry(main)> show-model Post --grep "content"
  content: text
```

It seems there is a `--grep` option for `ls` command in pry. I couldn't find a similar function with `show-model` command. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: no there is not `grep` like utility inside rails pry gem sorry .... but can't you check model attributes data types manually .... ?

Comment: You can `show-models --grep string` but that would list all models and only highlight the string matches.

Comment: @HaiderAli Yes, I can. But when the model become bigger, it's easier if there is grep-like function.

Comment: @wpp Highlight are also helpful, I prefer to show only matched result, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but it still pops up on top of a google search.

You can pass a flag to ls in pry that will basically do the same thing as piping to grep:

```
ls Post -G "content"
```

A full list of flags can be obtained by ls -h, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58879455/2709804

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'm using a `column_names` method and `Array#grep` for this purpose.

```
pry(main)> Post.column_names.grep(/string/)
[
   [0] "title"
   [1] "author"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant do this directly 
but you can write output of command to  a text file then use cat , grep on that
see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13380275

```
irb(main):015:0> f = File.new("statements.xml", 'w')
irb(main):016:0> f << Account.find(1).statements.to_xml
irb(main):017:0> f.close
```