# How is the ls command in Pry able to accept -l as an argument?

Tags: ruby, pry, pry-rails

I recently discovered that `ls` in pry can take an argument like so: `ls -l`.

My initial question is what the `-l` part actually is - it is clearly not a string or symbol, and there is no local variable or method `l` defined, so is there something else going on behind the scenes?

As an extension to my question, is `ls` just a "normal" Ruby method defined by pry, or does it behave slightly differently?

I also noted that you get a different output if you pass a string (`ls 'l'`) or symbol (`ls :l`). Is there a full reference of the possible options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `-l` works as the whole line is evaluated as a string by the `pry_eval` method. From that it matches the beginning against an existing command and extracts the rest as options to be passed in. From the Pry documentation:

> Nearly every piece of functionality in a Pry session is implemented as
>   a command. Commands are not methods and must start at the beginning of
>   a line, with no whitespace in between. Commands support a flexible
>   syntax and allow 'options' in the same way as shell commands

You can see the full list of options by running `ls -h`. This will return:

```
-m, --methods               Show public methods defined on the Object (default)
-M, --instance-methods      Show methods defined in a Module or Class
-p, --ppp                   Show public, protected (in yellow) and private (in green) methods
-q, --quiet                 Show only methods defined on object.singleton_class and object.class
-v, --verbose               Show methods and constants on all super-classes (ignores Pry.config.ls.ceiling)
-g, --globals               Show global variables, including those builtin to Ruby (in cyan)
-l, --locals                Show locals, including those provided by Pry (in red)
-c, --constants             Show constants, highlighting classes (in blue), and exceptions (in purple)
-i, --ivars                 Show instance variables (in blue) and class variables (in bright blue)
-G, --grep                  Filter output by regular expression
-h, --help                  Show this message.
```