# How can I have ruby logger log output to stdout as well as file?

Tags: ruby, logging

Someting like a tee functionality in logger.

Comment: Adding `| tee` before the file worked for me, so `Logger.new("| tee test.log")`. **Note the pipe.** This was from a tip on https://coderwall.com/p/y_b3ra/log-to-stdout-and-a-file-at-the-same-time

Comment: @mjwatts Use `tee --append test.log` to prevent overwrites.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can write a pseudo `IO` class that will write to multiple `IO` objects.  Something like:

```
class MultiIO
  def initialize(*targets)
     @targets = targets
  end

  def write(*args)
    @targets.each {|t| t.write(*args)}
  end

  def close
    @targets.each(&:close)
  end
end
```

Then set that as your log file:

```
log_file = File.open("log/debug.log", "a")
Logger.new MultiIO.new(STDOUT, log_file)
```

Every time `Logger` calls `puts` on your `MultiIO` object, it will write to both `STDOUT` and your log file.

**Edit:** I went ahead and figured out the rest of the interface.  A log device must respond to `write` and `close` (not `puts`).  As long as `MultiIO` responds to those and proxies them to the real IO objects, this should work.

Comment: if you look at the ctor of logger you will see that this will mess up log rotation.     
`def initialize(log = nil, opt = {})
      @dev = @filename = @shift_age = @shift_size = nil
      @mutex = LogDeviceMutex.new
      if log.respond_to?(:write) and log.respond_to?(:close)
 @dev = log
      else
 @dev = open_logfile(log)
 @dev.sync = true
 @filename = log
 @shift_age = opt[:shift_age] || 7
 @shift_size = opt[:shift_size] || 1048576
      end
    end`

Comment: Note in Ruby 2.2, `@targets.each(&:close)` is depreciated.

Comment: Worked for me until I realized I needed to periodically call :close on log_file to get log_file to update what logger had logged (essentially a "save"). STDOUT did not like :close being called on it, sort of defeating the MultoIO idea. Added a hack to skip :close except for class File, but wish I had a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 47):

@David's solution is very good. I've made a generic delegator class for multiple targets based on his code.

```
require 'logger'

class MultiDelegator
  def initialize(*targets)
    @targets = targets
  end

  def self.delegate(*methods)
    methods.each do |m|
      define_method(m) do |*args|
        @targets.map { |t| t.send(m, *args) }
      end
    end
    self
  end

  class <<self
    alias to new
  end
end

log_file = File.open("debug.log", "a")
log = Logger.new MultiDelegator.delegate(:write, :close).to(STDOUT, log_file)
```

Comment: Could you please explain, how this is better or what are enhanced utilities of this approach than the plain one suggested by David

Comment: It's separation of concerns. MultiDelegator only knows about delegating calls to multiple targets. The fact that a logging device needs a write and a close method is implemented in the caller. This makes MultiDelegator usable in other situations than logging.

Comment: Nice solution. I tried to use this to tee the output from my rake tasks to a log file. In order to get it to work with puts though (to be able to call $stdout.puts without getting "private method `puts' called"), I had to add a few more methods:
log_file = File.open("tmp/rake.log", "a")
$stdout = MultiDelegator.delegate(:write, :close, :puts, :print).to(STDOUT, log_file)
Would be nice if it were possible to create a Tee class that inherited from MultiDelegator, like you can do with the Delegator class in stdlib...

Comment: I came up with a Delegator-like implementation of this that I called DelegatorToAll. This way you don't have to list all the methods you want to delegate, since it will delegate all methods that are defined in the delegate class (IO):

class Tee < DelegateToAllClass(IO)
end
 
$stdout = Tee.new(STDOUT, File.open("#{__FILE__}.log", "a"))

See https://gist.github.com/TylerRick/4990898 for more details.

Comment: I am in love with your answer.

Comment: I really don't like Ruby, but this is nice. Well done.

Comment: I really like your solution, but it is not good as a generic delegator that can be used multiple times as every delegation pollutes all instances with new methods. I posted an answer bellow (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36659911/123376) that fixes this problem. I posted an answer rather than an edit since it may be educational to see the difference between the two implementations as I also posted examples.

Comment: Stick to David Answer. One example that simple thing doesn't need to be complicated.

Answer (score 39):

If you're in Rails 3 or 4, as [this blog post](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/08/07/rails-logging-into-several-backends/) points out, [Rails 4 has this functionality built in](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb). So you can do:

```
# config/environment/production.rb
file_logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/alternative-output.log"))
config.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(file_logger))
```

Or if you're on Rails 3, you can backport it:

```
# config/initializers/alternative_output_log.rb

# backported from rails4
module ActiveSupport
  class Logger < ::Logger
    # Broadcasts logs to multiple loggers. Returns a module to be
    # `extended`'ed into other logger instances.
    def self.broadcast(logger)
      Module.new do
        define_method(:add) do |*args, &block|
          logger.add(*args, &block)
          super(*args, &block)
        end

        define_method(:<<) do |x|
          logger << x
          super(x)
        end

        define_method(:close) do
          logger.close
          super()
        end

        define_method(:progname=) do |name|
          logger.progname = name
          super(name)
        end

        define_method(:formatter=) do |formatter|
          logger.formatter = formatter
          super(formatter)
        end

        define_method(:level=) do |level|
          logger.level = level
          super(level)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

file_logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/alternative-output.log"))
Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(file_logger))
```

Comment: is this applicable outside of rails, or rails only?

Comment: It's based on ActiveSupport, so if you have that dependency already, you can `extend` any `ActiveSupport::Logger` instance as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most effective answer, although I had some weirdness using the `config.logger.extend()` inside my environment configuration. Instead, I set `config.logger` to `STDOUT` in my environment, then extended the logger in different initializers.

Answer (score 20):

For those who like it simple:

```
log = Logger.new("| tee test.log") # note the pipe ( '|' )
log.info "hi" # will log to both STDOUT and test.log
```

[source](https://coderwall.com/p/y_b3ra/log-to-stdout-and-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Or print the message in the Logger formatter:

```
log = Logger.new("test.log")
log.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
    puts msg
    msg
end
log.info "hi" # will log to both STDOUT and test.log
```

I'm actually using this technique to print to a log file, a cloud logger service (logentries) and if it's dev environment - also print to STDOUT.

Comment: `"| tee test.log"` will overwrites  the old outputs, may be `"| tee -a test.log"` instead

Comment: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

Answer (score 13):

You can also add multiple device logging functionality directly into the Logger:

```
require 'logger'

class Logger
  # Creates or opens a secondary log file.
  def attach(name)
    @logdev.attach(name)
  end

  # Closes a secondary log file.
  def detach(name)
    @logdev.detach(name)
  end

  class LogDevice # :nodoc:
    attr_reader :devs

    def attach(log)
      @devs ||= {}
      @devs[log] = open_logfile(log)
    end

    def detach(log)
      @devs ||= {}
      @devs[log].close
      @devs.delete(log)
    end

    alias_method :old_write, :write
    def write(message)
      old_write(message)

      @devs ||= {}
      @devs.each do |log, dev|
        dev.write(message)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For instance:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.warn('This message goes to stdout')

logger.attach('logfile.txt')
logger.warn('This message goes both to stdout and logfile.txt')

logger.detach('logfile.txt')
logger.warn('This message goes just to stdout')
```

Answer (score 13):

While I quite like the other suggestions, I found I had this same issue but wanted the ability to have different logging levels for STDERR and the file.

I ended up with a routing strategy that multiplexes at the logger level rather than at the IO level, so that each logger could then operate at independent log-levels:

```rb
class MultiLogger
  def initialize(*targets)
    @targets = targets
  end

  %w(log debug info warn error fatal unknown).each do |m|
    define_method(m) do |*args|
      @targets.map { |t| t.send(m, *args) }
    end
  end
end

stderr_log = Logger.new(STDERR)
file_log = Logger.new(File.open('logger.log', 'a'))

stderr_log.level = Logger::INFO
file_log.level = Logger::DEBUG

log = MultiLogger.new(stderr_log, file_log)
```

Comment: I like this solution best as it is (1) simple, and (2) encourages you to re-use your Logger classes instead of assuming everything goes to a file.  In my case I'd like to log to STDOUT and a GELF appender for Graylog.  Having a `MultiLogger` like @dsz describes is a great fit. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Added section to handle pseudovariables (setters/getters)

Answer (score 9):

Here's another implementation, inspired by **@jonas054**'s answer.

This uses a pattern similar to [`Delegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html). This way you don't have to list all the methods you want to delegate, since it will delegate all methods that are defined in any of the target objects:

```
class Tee < DelegateToAllClass(IO)
end

$stdout = Tee.new(STDOUT, File.open("#{__FILE__}.log", "a"))
```

You should be able to use this with Logger as well.

delegate_to_all.rb is available from here: https://gist.github.com/TylerRick/4990898

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty (ref: https://coderwall.com/p/y_b3ra/log-to-stdout-and-a-file-at-the-same-time)

```
require 'logger'
ll=Logger.new('| tee script.log')
ll.info('test')
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written a little RubyGem that allows you to do several of these things:

```
# Pipe calls to an instance of Ruby's logger class to $stdout
require 'teerb'

log_file = File.open("debug.log", "a")
logger = Logger.new(TeeRb::IODelegate.new(log_file, STDOUT))

logger.warn "warn"
$stderr.puts "stderr hello"
puts "stdout hello"
```

You can find the code on github: [teerb](https://github.com/phuesler/teerb)

Comment: Thanks. This is quite clean.

Answer (score 3):

@jonas054's answer above is great, but it pollutes the `MultiDelegator` class with every new delegate. If you use `MultiDelegator` several times, it will keep adding methods to the class, which is undesirable. (See bellow for example)

Here is the same implementation, but using anonymous classes so the methods don't pollute the delegator class.

```
class BetterMultiDelegator

  def self.delegate(*methods)
    Class.new do
      def initialize(*targets)
        @targets = targets
      end

      methods.each do |m|
        define_method(m) do |*args|
          @targets.map { |t| t.send(m, *args) }
        end
      end

      class <<self
        alias to new
      end
    end # new class
  end # delegate

end
```

Here is an example of the method pollution with the original implementation, contrasted with the modified implementation:

```
tee = MultiDelegator.delegate(:write).to(STDOUT)
tee.respond_to? :write
# => true
tee.respond_to? :size
# => false
```

All is good above. `tee` has a `write` method, but no `size` method as expected. Now, consider when we create another delegate:

```
tee2 = MultiDelegator.delegate(:size).to("bar")
tee2.respond_to? :size
# => true
tee2.respond_to? :write
# => true   !!!!! Bad
tee.respond_to? :size
# => true   !!!!! Bad
```

Oh no, `tee2` responds to `size` as expected, but it also responds to `write` because of the first delegate. Even `tee` now responds to `size` because of the method pollution.

Contrast this to the anonymous class solution, everything is as expected:

```
see = BetterMultiDelegator.delegate(:write).to(STDOUT)
see.respond_to? :write
# => true
see.respond_to? :size
# => false

see2 = BetterMultiDelegator.delegate(:size).to("bar")
see2.respond_to? :size
# => true
see2.respond_to? :write
# => false
see.respond_to? :size
# => false
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you restricted to the standard logger?

If not you may use [log4r](https://rubygems.org/gems/log4r):

```
require 'log4r' 

LOGGER = Log4r::Logger.new('mylog')
LOGGER.outputters << Log4r::StdoutOutputter.new('stdout')
LOGGER.outputters << Log4r::FileOutputter.new('file', :filename => 'test.log') #attach to existing log-file

LOGGER.info('aa') #Writs on STDOUT and sends to file
```

One advantage: You could also define different log-levels for stdout and file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using `ActiveSupport`, then I would highly recommend checking out `ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast`, which is an excellent and very concise way to add additional log destinations to a logger.

In fact, if you are using Rails 4+ (as of [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/983bf6d456d29bfb9c8b497991e65682ca4d1ce4)), you don't need to do *anything* to get the desired behavior — at least if you're using the `rails console`. Whenever you use the `rails console`, Rails *[automatically](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L63)* extends `Rails.logger` such that it outputs both to its usual file destination (`log/production.log`, for example) and `STDERR`:

```
    console do |app|
      …
      unless ActiveSupport::Logger.logger_outputs_to?(Rails.logger, STDERR, STDOUT)
        console = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDERR)
        Rails.logger.extend ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast console
      end
      ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = false
    end
```

For some unknown and unfortunate reason, this method is [undocumented](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Logger.html) but you can refer to the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb#L23) or blog posts to learn how it works or see examples.

https://www.joshmcarthur.com/til/2018/08/16/logging-to-multiple-destinations-using-activesupport-4.html has another example:

```rb
require "active_support/logger"
console_logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
file_logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("my_log.log")
combined_logger = console_logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(file_logger))

combined_logger.debug "Debug level"
…
```

Answer (score 1):

I went to the same idea of "Delegating all methods to sub-elements" that other people already explored, but am returning for each of them the return value of the last call of the method.
If I didn't, it broke `logger-colors` which were expecting an `Integer` and map was returning an `Array`.

```
class MultiIO
  def self.delegate_all
    IO.methods.each do |m|
      define_method(m) do |*args|
        ret = nil
        @targets.each { |t| ret = t.send(m, *args) }
        ret
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(*targets)
    @targets = targets
    MultiIO.delegate_all
  end
end
```

This will redelegate every method to all targets, and return only the return value of the last call.

Also, if you want colors, STDOUT or STDERR must be put last, since it's the only two were colors are supposed to be output. But then, it will also output colors to your file.

```
logger = Logger.new MultiIO.new(File.open("log/test.log", 'w'), STDOUT)
logger.error "Roses are red"
logger.unknown "Violets are blue"
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way.
If you're using tagged logging and need tags in another logfile as well, you could do it in this way

```
# backported from rails4
# config/initializers/active_support_logger.rb
module ActiveSupport
 class Logger < ::Logger

 # Broadcasts logs to multiple loggers. Returns a module to be
 # `extended`'ed into other logger instances.
 def self.broadcast(logger)
  Module.new do
    define_method(:add) do |*args, &block|
      logger.add(*args, &block)
      super(*args, &block)
    end

    define_method(:<<) do |x|
      logger << x
      super(x)
    end

    define_method(:close) do
      logger.close
      super()
    end

    define_method(:progname=) do |name|
      logger.progname = name
      super(name)
    end

    define_method(:formatter=) do |formatter|
      logger.formatter = formatter
      super(formatter)
    end

    define_method(:level=) do |level|
      logger.level = level
      super(level)
    end

   end # Module.new
 end # broadcast

 def initialize(*args)
   super
   @formatter = SimpleFormatter.new
 end

  # Simple formatter which only displays the message.
  class SimpleFormatter < ::Logger::Formatter
   # This method is invoked when a log event occurs
   def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
   element = caller[4] ? caller[4].split("/").last : "UNDEFINED"
    "#{Thread.current[:activesupport_tagged_logging_tags]||nil } # {time.to_s(:db)} #{severity} #{element} -- #{String === msg ? msg : msg.inspect}\n"
   end
  end

 end # class Logger
end # module ActiveSupport

custom_logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/alternative_#{Rails.env}.log"))
Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(custom_logger))
```

After this you'll get uuid tags in alternative logger

```
["fbfea87d1d8cc101a4ff9d12461ae810"] 2015-03-12 16:54:04 INFO logger.rb:28:in `call_app' -- 
["fbfea87d1d8cc101a4ff9d12461ae810"] 2015-03-12 16:54:04 INFO   logger.rb:31:in `call_app' -- Started POST "/psp/entrypoint" for 192.168.56.1 at 2015-03-12 16:54:04 +0700
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Simple, reliable and works brilliantly. Thanks!

Note that `ActiveSupport::Logger` works out of the box with this - you just need to use `Rails.logger.extend` with `ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

One more option ;-)

```
require 'logger'

class MultiDelegator
  def initialize(*targets)
    @targets = targets
  end

  def method_missing(method_sym, *arguments, &block)
    @targets.each do |target|
      target.send(method_sym, *arguments, &block) if target.respond_to?(method_sym)
    end
  end
end

log = MultiDelegator.new(Logger.new(STDOUT), Logger.new(File.open("debug.log", "a")))

log.info('Hello ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplification of @rado's solution.

```
def delegator(*methods)
  Class.new do
    def initialize(*targets)
      @targets = targets
    end

    methods.each do |m|
      define_method(m) do |*args|
        @targets.map { |t| t.send(m, *args) }
      end
    end

    class << self
      alias for new
    end
  end # new class
end # delegate
```

It has all the same benefits as his without the need of the outer class wrapper. Its a useful utility to have in a separate ruby file.

Use it as a one-liner to generate delegator instances like so:

```
IO_delegator_instance = delegator(:write, :read).for(STDOUT, STDERR)
IO_delegator_instance.write("blah")
```

OR use it as a factory like so:

```
logger_delegator_class = delegator(:log, :warn, :error)
secret_delegator = logger_delegator_class(main_logger, secret_logger)
secret_delegator.warn("secret")

general_delegator = logger_delegator_class(main_logger, debug_logger, other_logger) 
general_delegator.log("message")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Loog::Tee` object from [`loog`](https://github.com/yegor256/loog) gem:

```rb
require 'loog'
logger = Loog::Tee.new(first, second)
```

Exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I also has this need recently so I implemented a library that does this. I just discovered this StackOverflow question, so I'm putting it out there for anyone that needs it: https://github.com/agis/multi_io.

Compared to the other solutions mentioned here, this strives to be an `IO` object of its own, so it can be used as a drop-in replacement for other regular IO objects (files, sockets etc.)

That said, I've not yet implemented all the standard IO methods, but those that are, follow the IO semantics (e.g. for example, `#write` returns the sum of the number of bytes written to all the underlying IO targets).

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit `Logger` and override the `write` method:

```
class LoggerWithStdout < Logger
  def initialize(*)
    super

    def @logdev.write(msg)
      super

      puts msg
    end
  end
end

logger = LoggerWithStdout.new('path/to/log_file.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IO.popen` with tee.
[Method: IO.popen — Documentation for core (3.0.2)](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.popen)

```rb
$logger = Logger.new(IO.popen(["tee", "-a", "debug.log"], "wb"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I like the **MultiIO** approach. It works well with Ruby **Logger**. If you use **pure IO** it stops working because it lacks some methods that IO objects are expected to have. **Pipes** were mentioned before here: [How can I have ruby logger log output to stdout as well as file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407141/how-can-i-have-ruby-logger-log-output-to-stdout-as-well-as-file#comment63470228_6407141). Here is what works best for me.

```
def watch(cmd)
  output = StringIO.new
  IO.popen(cmd) do |fd|
    until fd.eof?
      bit = fd.getc
      output << bit
      $stdout.putc bit
    end
  end
  output.rewind
  [output.read, $?.success?]
ensure
  output.close
end

result, success = watch('./my/shell_command as a String')
```

**Note** I know this doesn't answer the question directly but it is strongly related. Whenever I searched for output to multiple IOs I came across this thread.So, I hope you find this useful too.

Answer (score -3):

I think your STDOUT is used for critical runtime info and errors raised.

So I use

```
  $log = Logger.new('process.log', 'daily')
```

to log debug and regular logging, and then wrote a few

```
  puts "doing stuff..."
```

where I need to see STDOUT information that my scripts were running at all!

Bah, just my 10 cents :-)