# Removing color decorations from strings before writing them to logfile

Tags: ruby, logging, colors, ansi-escape

I use the ruby logger like this:

```
$logger = Logger.new MultiIO.new($stdout, log_file)
```

Where the `MultiIO` is a class I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407200/674039).  This works great, mostly, but I am using `'colored'` rubygem to give coloured output on the terminal.  Unfortunately this ends up in the logfile too as ANSI escapes looking like `[32mPASS[0m` or some similar non-printable characters rubbish.

What is the best approach to sanitise the logfile strings whilst keeping colours for the tty strings?  I don't mind monkey-patching `Logger` or `MultiIO`, but I absolutely don't want two different calls for logfile and screen.

Comment: I've never had any problems with ANSI escape characters in my log files. Most Unix tools (`cat`, `more`, `less`, `grep`, `tail` etc.) handle them just fine.

Comment: Yes, I know, unfortunately the kind of people that will be needing these will probably be using notepad.exe or gedit at best.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my current solution

```
class ColourBlind
  def initialize(*targets)
     @targets = targets
  end

  def write(*args)
    @targets.each {|t| t.write(*args.map {|x| x.gsub(/\e\[(\d+)m/, '')}.compact)}
  end

  def close
    @targets.each(&:close)
  end
end
```

And then:

```
$logger = Logger.new MultiIO.new($stdout, ColourBlind.new(log_file))
```

Comment: `/\e\[(\d+)(;\d+)*m/` should be better, since sometimes people put foreground and background color together in some telnet programs.

Comment: I couldn't get colorize's method to work, but this answer (and the improvement-comment above) seems to work. Not sure why colorize's doesn't work, nor why it doesn't use this simpler regex...

Answer (score 12):

For removal of ANSI colors, I would recommend

```
string_with_ascii = "..."
string_no_ascii = string_with_ascii.gsub(/\e\[([;\d]+)?m/, '')
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [colorize gem](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize/blob/9f18a27e260746cc7092d9f03403711ab62d7167/lib/colorize.rb):

```
class String
  REGEXP_PATTERN = /\033\[([0-9]+);([0-9]+);([0-9]+)m(.+?)\033\[0m|([^\033]+)/m

  def uncolorize
    self.scan(REGEXP_PATTERN).inject("") do |str, match|
      str << (match[3] || match[4])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Gem has been updated, and uncolorize doesn't seem to strip colors but rather add the escape to the output.

Comment: UNCOLORIZE_REGEXP = /\e\[[;m\d]+/