# ruby: unable to use logger with rspec

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I am trying to add logging to a simple rspec test. I am using Watir to drive Chrome within the spec and this works fine. I am unable to get logs using the "Logger" library.

This is my spec:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rspec'
require 'logger'

describe 'ui tests' do
  let(:browser) { browser ||= Watir::Browser.new :chrome }

  let(:log) {
    log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    log = Logger.new('watir.tests.log', 'daily')
    log.level = Logger::DEBUG
  }

  before {
    browser.goto 'http://translate.google.com'
  }
  after { browser.close }

  context 'simple tests' do
    it 'simple test' do
      log.info("Running simple test")
      browser.text_field(:id => "source").set("ost")

      # actual test/asserts here

    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that I am unable to call any logging method such as log.info inside the example. I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) ui tests simple tests simple test
Failure/Error: log.info("Running simple test")
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `info' for 0:Fixnum
```

Why is this failing? Is it a scope issue? If I comment out the `log.info` the spec runs fine. I can use any methods on the "browser" object (for example, the call to browser.text_field) inside the example without a problem.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your `let(:log)` block does not return the Logger instance. Simply append a line with `log` before the closing `}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `log` is the last thing evaluated inside the `let(:log) { }` block, which is `Logger::DEBUG`.  This constant just corresponds to the `Fixnum` 0, and there's no method called `info` for 0.  Try this instead:

```
let(:log) { 
  Logger.new(STDOUT).tap { |l| l.level = Logger::DEBUG }
}
```

By the way, what are you trying to do with setting `log = Logger.new(STDOUT)` and then immediately reassigning `log = Logger.new('watir.tests.log', 'daily')`?

Comment: I'm trying to get logging on both STDOUT and also to a file. I guess this isn't the right way to do this? I'm coming from log4j where you have appenders, and am (quite obviously) new to ruby.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407141/how-can-i-have-ruby-logger-log-output-to-stdout-as-well-as-file

Comment: Your solution works, but I can't understand the functional programming magic. Can you post a link to an explanation of what the feature is and how it works?

Comment: `let(:foo) { do_stuff }` is essentially equivalent to `def foo; @foo ||= do_stuf; end`.  `foo.tap { |bar| do_stuff }` is a little harder, but it's often the same as `bar = foo; do_stuff; foo;`.

Comment: let: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let  
tap: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-tap

Comment: Thought I'd update this post with what I finally settled on. To get logging to both STDOUT and file, I abandoned the Logger hacks and used log4r instead. Much happier with log4r overall.