# RSpec log showing in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Where should I configure this for log to be in `log/test.log` or what keyword should I look in my project to change this config.

I tried with `log` in `spec` no results, there is no `STDOUT` in `spec` either.

Comment: Similar question was brought up in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232068/ruby-unable-to-use-logger-with-rspec

Answer (score 2):

run rspec with -o option or you could specify this option in `.rspec` file.

For eg:

`rspec -o log/test.log`

But the above will overwrite log file each run. In order to save the previous log messages, you need to do as below,

`rspec >> log/test.log`

`>>` will always append to log file.