# Printing to console and writing to a file at the same time Ruby

Tags: ruby, output

I'm trying to write some code in ruby that'll allow me to print the output of a test to the console and printing that same output to a file. The way I currently do it below seems redundant.

```
f = File.open("ExampleText.txt", "w")

if example1 > example2 then
    print("Do it")
    f.print("Do it")
else 
    print("Don't do it")
    f.print ("Don't do it")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple method to do what you are doing and call the method instead in your conditions. Here:

```
def write_and_display(str, file)
  puts str
  file.puts str
end

f = File.open("ExampleText.txt", "w")
if example1 > example2
  write_and_display("do this", f)
else
  write_and_display("dont do it", f)
end
```

Alternatively, you can also write a pseudo IO class that will write to multiple IO objects. Something discussed at this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407200/3035830