# Causing the Ruby Logger to autoflush

Tags: ruby, logging

I am using the standard Ruby 2.2 Logger (i.e. not the Logger from Rails), and since I want to use it as rotating logger, I call it with shift_age and shift_time and pass to it a filename, not a open file handle, like this:

```
Logger.new('my_file.log', 4, 100_000)
```

I would like to make the output of this logger unbuffered, but I did not find any method in the Logger interface which would allow this.

In the particular way I am using this logger (I am wrapping the Logger with my own class, which does customization), I have one central point in my code where each logging request is going through, so if I could get at the underlying IO object, I could do a sync at this point, but I also don't know how to find this IO object.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by unbuffered? Any time you write `logger.info` for example the output is immediately present in the logfile.

Comment: May I ask you, where this is documented? I didn't find in the docs any mention of the fact that Logger would set sync to true on its IO handle, but when I googled the topic, I found in various forums discussions mentioning that the Logger output would *not* be automatically flushed (however I didn't find there any useful solution to this problem either). Maybe I'll have to dig into the source code of Logger to get an authoritative answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set `sync`. It's already set by `Logger` upon logfile creation:

```
def create_logfile(filename)
  begin
    logdev = open(filename, (File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT | File::EXCL))
    logdev.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
    logdev.sync = true
    add_log_header(logdev)
    logdev.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
  rescue Errno::EEXIST
    # file is created by another process
    logdev = open_logfile(filename)
    logdev.sync = true
  end
  logdev
end
```

Source:
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/logger.rb

Comment: I want both, `print logs in the terminal` and `create a log file` in the end. How can I do that?

Comment: @paul If you want to do both at the same time, it looks like here are a few solutions for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407141/how-can-i-have-ruby-logger-log-output-to-stdout-as-well-as-file