# IO streams inconsistencies in different versions of ruby

Tags: ruby, irb

I am trying to create a way to mirror all three standard (input,out and error) streams of a ruby program to different files.
I was able to do that for output `stdout` and error `stderr` streams.
However there is inconsistencies between different ruby version on how they handle IO streams.

Bottom line is
**How do I handle stream duplication in older versions of ruby** (point 2) ?

Issue Summary

1. Older ruby versions don't support variadic arguments while new version does, that can be handled.
2. On same older versions, even if I try to work around it by `join` ing arguments, stream contents are duplicated.

---

1. **Variadic arguments issue**
   In ruby `2.1.x` and ruby `2.2.x`, `$stdout` accepts only single arguments.

So for those version of ruby

```rb
$stdout.write("Test") # works
```

while this doesn't work

```rb
$stdout.write("Hello","Test")

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from (pry):6:in `write'
```

However for ruby version `2.5.x` and `2.6.x` variable parameters works

```rb
$stdout.write("Hello")
$stdout.write("This","works", "as", "well")
```

2. **Duplication of stream content**, if I add version specific code to handle stream parameters, older ruby version end up duplicating the stream content.

   - Older ruby version

```
driver.rb:4 in `puts` --> This is it driver.rb:4 in `puts` -->
```

while on

- New ruby versions

```
driver.rb:4 in `puts` --> This is it
```

Here is the code

---

1. reox.rb

```rb
require_relative 'reox_io.rb'
require_relative 'reox_file.rb'

class Reox
    DEFAULT_RECORDING_PATH = "recordings" 

    def initialize(recording_path)
        @recording_paths = recording_path || DEFAULT_RECORDING_PATH  
    end

    def self.record 
        input_log,output_log,error_log = setup_files
        $stdout = ReoxIO.new(STDOUT,output_log)
        $stderr = ReoxIO.new(STDERR,error_log)
        yield
    end


    private 

    def self.setup_files
        ["input.log","output.log","error.log"].map do |file_name|
            self.setup_file(file_name)
        end 
    end

    def self.setup_file(file_name)
        file = ReoxFile.open(File.join(__dir__,file_name),"a")
        file.sync = true
        file
    end
end
```

2. reox_file.rb

```rb
class ReoxFile < File 
end
```

3. reox_io.rb

```rb
# Insipired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407200
require_relative 'reox_file.rb'
class ReoxIO
   $LOG_SEPARATOR = " --> ".freeze
   def initialize(*streams)
     @streams = streams
     @verbose = true
   end 

   def write(*content)
     @streams.each do |stream| 
      if @verbose and stream.is_a? ReoxFile
        stream.write([caller[2],$LOG_SEPARATOR,*content].join)
      else
        stream.write(*content)
      end    
     end 
   end

   def flush
    @streams.each(&:flush)
   end

   def close
    @streams.each(&:close) 
   end

end
```

4. driver.rb

```rb
require_relative 'reox.rb'
Reox.record do 
  puts "This is it" 
end
```

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: @anothermh 
My question is how I do the tackle the stream duplication in older ruby versions ?

Comment: `require` declarations should omit the `.rb` extension. That's only necessary if for some reason the extension is something other than `.rb`.

Comment: @tadman Agreed. 
I don't think it will lead to stream duplication, though ?

Comment: I'm  not sure what the question is. Yes, Ruby has evolved since the older versions and now you can write multiple things in one call. You couldn't before. If you need backwards compatibility then do it the old way. As for the duplication issue, I can't see where that arises.

Comment: I would check what streams you're writing to as it's probably the case you're writing to two copies of the same stream, or both STDOUT and STDERR at the same time.

Comment: Yes, first point can be handled. 
It is the second issue, older version of ruby are considering the write to `stream.write([caller[2],$LOG_SEPARATOR,*content].join)` like a geniune output produced by the program and re-adding it again.

Comment: Yes, that can be the issue. 
I will check again in the morning and revert back. 
I cannot use byebug or binding.irb/pry since it causes the program to freeze.

Comment: So, I was able to get it working by adding a check for empty content.
Somehow writing to file stream creates a new stream event where content is empty and that's written as a new line.
`if @verbose and stream.is_a? ReoxFile and not content.join.strip.empty?`
fixed this. 
But still no idea why writing to file caused the IO to intercept another write.