# /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:83:in `exist?': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError) if File.exist?(path)

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to install `CodeDeploy agent` on EC2 and I followed the steps:

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install ruby
sudo yum -y install wget
cd /home/ec2-user
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
sudo chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
```

I can see a file named `install` is downloaded and ruby is installed too
`ruby --version => ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [x86_64-linux]`
but when I run `sudo ./install auto` it throws this error below
**NOTE** I have toggled between `root` user and `ec2-user` but it didn't work!
**NOTE** I don't have an Rudy code to run

```
/usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:83:in `exist?': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
          if File.exist?(path)
                         ^^^^
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:83:in `set_dev'
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:18:in `initialize'
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger.rb:587:in `new'
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger.rb:587:in `initialize'
    from ./install:43:in `new'
    from ./install:43:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I am also getting same error, have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are following Stephane's DevOps course from Udemy. I had quite a bit of a problem myself trying to figure out a workaround from giving root-level permissions to the ec2-user and trying to follow @anothermh 's answer by editing the logger_device.RB file.

This issue arises due to version incompatibilities between the new amazon 2023 AMI and the Ruby Logger class. What you need to do to fix this is as follows:

- Terminate the EC2 instance
- Create a new EC2 instance
- Choose the following AMI version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW4nb.png
- Connect to the new instance
- Copy and paste all commands

Note: Remember to reassign the IAM Role when you create the new instance.

The code deploy agent will now be successfully installed and working. Hope this helps!

Comment: There are more details on this github issue https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/355

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the `install` script. Look at lines 42-43:

```rb
# if we are being run in a terminal, log to stdout and the log file.
@log = Logger.new(Proxy.new(File.open(log_file_path, 'a+'), $stdout))
```

That does not work for [the `Logger` class](https://github.com/ruby/logger/blob/42448f530e83029a54594f6a846b4e3875e8a986/lib/logger/log_device.rb#L82-L86):

```rb
if log.respond_to?(:path) and path = log.path
  if File.exist?(path)
    @filename = path
  end
end
```

Because the object being passed to `Logger.new` *does* respond to `:path`:

```rb
def path
  @targets.map do |target|
    if target.respond_to?(:path)
      target.__send__(:path)
    else
      # default to to_s since it's just used as a label for log statements.
      target.__send__(:to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know why the script was written that way. Maybe it worked in an earlier version of Ruby. The `Logger` class is kind of garbage so who knows.

Just change line 43 so that it doesn't use the `Proxy` class, choosing either to log to a file or to log to stdout:

```rb
@log = Logger.new($stdout)
# or
@log = Logger.new(File.open(log_file_path, 'a+'))
```

If you really cared to you could make it [log to multiple destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6407141/3784008) but given you're just trying to run the script I don't think you care about that. Changing line 43 is likely all that you need to do to resolve this bug.